# How to read from a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text

EDIT:

Due to random downvotes still coming in I guess I can clarify this some more.

Essentially the question is asking **how do you read from a text file in C#**.  The code i thought would work is below.  The answer provides what actually works.  Please comment when you downvote.

OLD:

I'm using Microsoft visual studios to write a video game, but can't seem to get it to take in input from a text file.  If i comment out the following line and and things based off of it, it works fine.  If I add only this line back in then it runs but the window never pops up.

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("map1.txt");
```

I also have the statement to be sure it is included.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

If you'd like more code I can post it but it's a pretty large amount.

OLD-EDIT:  To clarify, no window would pop up like it normally would when i ran my game but also no error messages would popup either.  My txt file was included in the content but for some reason wasn't working.  I used the full path and now it works!

Comment: Do you mean the program hangs at exactly that code line? If you step throgh the program line by line, what happens there?

Comment: Is your txt file in the directory the program is being run in?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get an exception on `File.ReadAllLines` (which could easily happen if the file does not exist)? Did you try using a full file path (instead of relying on the current dir)?

Comment: Please let us know if an answer was helpful!

Comment: oops! sorry thought i clicked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a fullpath here, as the file might not be in the place 
that your program is trying to read from (and hence you get a problem in reading it).

```
string fullPath = @"C:\MyFantasticVideoGame\map.txt";
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
```